# Form isnt seen in Netlify dashboard from Gatsby site

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify

I have a problem with Netlify form + Gatsby. I can't see my form in Netlify dashboard.

My form locates in Drawer component that isn't seen by default but only opens by click.

I have already added all required fields for initialization but nothing happens

```
<form name="contact" method="post" data-netlify="true" data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field">...</form>
```

My current submit function:

```
const onSubmitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const form = e.target

    fetch("/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
      body: encode({
        "form-name": form.getAttribute("name"),
        ...formData,
      }),
    })
      .then(() => {
        dispatch(clearCart())
        setFormData(initialFormData)
        dispatch(setCartStage("complete"))
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must provide a `hidden` input with `name="form-name"` and with the same `value` as you want your form to appear in your dashboard:

```
<form name="contact" method="post" data-netlify="true" data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field">
  {/* You still need to add the hidden input with the form name to your JSX form */}
  <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contact" />
  ...
</form>
```

Repeating the `hidden` `form-name` field is absolutely necessary. If you omit this field or mistype the name, your entries will either throw an error or will get lost because Netlify won't know how to match this request with your form.

In addition, your `POST` request must include this field in the body. An ideal submit should look like:

```
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const form = e.target
    fetch('/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
      body: encode({
        'form-name': form.getAttribute('name'), 
        ...state, // your fields paired with key: name
      }),
    })
      .then(() => navigate(form.getAttribute('action')))
      .catch((error) => alert(error))
  }
```

You can find detailed information in this [article (provided by Netlify)](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2017/07/20/how-to-integrate-netlifys-form-handling-in-a-react-app/) and a [live example and source code in this GitHub repository](https://github.com/sw-yx/gatsby-netlify-form-example-v2/blob/master/src/pages/contact.js)

---

> I receive 404 when submitting

I think your origin path is wrong. Your form now looks good but Netlify can't find the requested URL.

[image]

Comment: Ferran, thank you for the response. I have added hidden input and have changed my handleSubmit function but nothing happens. I still DONT see any forms in my Netlify Dashboard. As i wrote before my form inside component with ```display: "none"``` by default and its shown only by click action. Is it possible Netlify bot cant find my form because of this display: none? 

In my case i have Drawer with 3 steps: 1st step is cart overview with cart items, 2nd step is cart form and 3rd step is "Thank you" page"

Comment: It doesn't mind if it's `display: none` if the action fires properly. Could you try checking your network tab and see if it's sending a`POST` request? Would be interesting a snapshot of the request as well as your submit function.

Comment: I have added my submit function

Comment: Can you confirm that is sending a `POST` request `onSubmit`?

Comment: I receive 404 when submitting

Comment: Try adding an `action='/'` in your `<form>` tag

Comment: I added action='/' but nothing happens. My form is in React component but not in Gatsby page template. You can check this form in the cart second step here [link](https://minimal-store.netlify.app/shop/women/shoes/Women's-Shoe-Nike-Air-Force-1-Shadow) You have to chose size and add to the cart. After that just click on green button inside cart

Comment: My guess is that Netlify can't find your requested URL.

Comment: Thanks for checking but how can i fix this? And my form still isnt seen in Netlify dashboard